# drupal views add date to node taxonomy view

Tags: php, drupal, taxonomy

I just created a drupal view.
It is showing my nodes from a specific taxonomy with read more links.

All is working fine.

This is my code:

```
<?php
// $Id: views-view-unformatted.tpl.php,v 1.6 2008/10/01 20:52:11 merlinofchaos Exp $
/**
 * @file views-view-unformatted.tpl.php
 * Default simple view template to display a list of rows.
 *
 * @ingroup views_templates
 */
?>
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div class="<?php print $classes[$id]; ?>">
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

From:
views-view-unformatted--test-clubnieuws.tpl

Now I just want to add the node publish date after the node title.
How to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php if (!empty($date)): ?>     
<?php print $date; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I suppose you don't need the if statement as if it has a title it should have a date.

Comment: it's really that simple? I can't try it now I'm at work but thanks I'll try this evening